# Trouble parsing XML with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm working on an exercise to implement an infinite scroller that pulls info from a MySQL database that I've set up.  My scroller portion seems to work, my db, connection, and query seem fine when tested in another file, and I believe my XML file is structured as I want it.  However, when I get to the portion of my code where I try to parse the XML, retrieving data in the element tags and appending it to my html, I'm getting the following error in Chrome's inspector window:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Resource id #2<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response><commentData>...(the rest of my XML file)
```

I'm fairly new to programming, and am at a loss as to what's causing the problem. Here's my code below.  I have a few things commented out, so hopefully that doesn't throw anyone off.  Also, the include.inc.php file just contains the functions used to connect to the db and execute the queries.  Thanks.

**AJAXscroller.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Scroller with AJAX!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/scroller.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./include/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./include/scroller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="info"></div>


    <section id="userComments">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... </p> <!-- my code longer to fill page & requre scroll -->
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... tulla, semper gravida magna velit eu sem.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... tulla, semper gravida magna velit eu sem.</p>   
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... tulla, semper gravida magna velit eu sem.</p>   
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... tulla, semper gravida magna velit eu sem.</p>       
    </section>
    <div id="loaderGif"><img src="img/220.gif"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**scroller.js:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() 
    {
        $("#loaderGif").hide(); 
        var start = 0;     //variable to indicate the starting row in the db query
        var numRows = 30;  //this is the number of db rows to fetch with each query


        $(window).scroll(
            function()
            {
                var top = $(this).scrollTop();
                var txt = "scrollTop: " + top + 
                          "<br/>Win H: " + $(this).height() + 
                          "<br/>Page H: " + ($(this).height() + top) +
                          "<br/>Doc H: " + $(document).height();

                $("#info").html(txt);

            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
                {
                    $("#loaderGif").fadeIn(2000);
                    $.post("./include/AJAXscroll.php", {m: start, n: numRows}, function(xml) 
                       {
                           //code that happens when we get response

                           $("commentData", xml).each(
                               function()
                               {

                                   var userName = $(this).find("username").text();
                                   var comment = $(this).find("comment").text();
                                   var created = $(this).find("created").text();

                                   var str = "<hr><p>" + userName + " commented at " + created + "</p>" + comment;  

                                   $("#userComments").append(str);
                                   $("#loaderGif").fadeOut(2000);                          

                               }
                           );
                        }
                    ); 
                }  
            }
        );  
    }
);
```

**AJAXscroll.php:**

```
<?php

    include ("./include.inc.php");
    $link = connect();
    $db = "myTestDB";

    $m = $_POST["m"];
    $n = $_POST["n"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE username='Donna' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,30";
//  $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE username='Donna' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT " . m . "," . n;
    $res = send_sql($sql, $link, $db);
    echo $res;

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $response = $dom->createElement("response");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))         // create the XML file
    {
        $commentData = $dom->createElement("commentData");

        $username = $dom->createElement("username");
        $usernameValue = $dom->createTextNode($row["username"]);
        $username->appendChild($usernameValue);

        $comment = $dom->createElement("comment");
        $commentValue = $dom->createTextNode($row["comment"]);
        $comment->appendChild($commentValue);

        $created = $dom->createElement("created");
        $createdValue = $dom->createTextNode($row["created"]);
        $created->appendChild($createdValue);

        $commentData->appendChild($username);  
        $commentData->appendChild($comment);
        $commentData->appendChild($created);

        $response->appendChild($commentData);
     }  
     $dom->appendChild($response);
     $xmlString = $dom->saveXML();
//   $dom->save("myXML.xml");
     header('Content-type: text/xml'); 
     echo $xmlString;
?>
```

Comment: Do not output `Resource id #2` before you output the XML.

Comment: Just curious, but why the downvote? Just because the mistake was stupid?

Comment: no, a stupid mistake alone doesn't make the DV. Posting large amounts of unrelated code and not pinpointing the question to what you actually want to learn about (e.g. did you never wonder where how `Resource id #2` went in front of your XML?) - in short: move the mouse over the downvote button you see a little title that explains it.

Comment: Exactly why i prefaced things by saying I'm new to all of this.  If I knew what the root of the problem was then I would have been more direct.  My intention wasn't to flood the post with unrelated code, but to rather give as full a picture as possible, since I didn't know where the problem was coming from.  My suspected area would have been of no help, as it was the code that parsed the XML in the JS file.

Comment: just take the error message and paste it into google. https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+Error%3A+Syntax+error%2C+unrecognized+expression%3A&aq=f&oq=Uncaught+Error%3A+Syntax+error%2C+unrecognized+expression%3A&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62.3041&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing content before your xml data this causes problems in parsing the xml. Remove the `echo $res;` and you should parse the xml fine.

Comment: That did it.  I'm an idiot.  I had added that echo earlier today when troubleshooting another error, and didn't even realize that  I still had it there (wasn't really focusing on the PHP file as I thought I was in the clear with that file.  Thanks...sometimes the obvious is right there in front of us.